# Computer won't connect to network after coming out of suspend

Tags: networking, suspend, power-management, cinnamon

So I am new to Linux and I am not very good at CLI and much prefer gui instead. But I have 3 issues that might all be stemming from my suspend mode. When I close the lid of my laptop it goes into suspend mode. When I resume work I usually cannot get internet (wired). I usually have to restart to get a connection. Also lately I will lose my connection randomly while using my computer ( this has just started with in the last 2 days). The other is Cinnamon usually crashes after I resume from suspend. Any ideas? I have been trying to scour the internet with no avail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code after coming out of suspend mode for resuming the network services:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```